# disable visual editor and media button

Tags: wordpress

created plugin to add "posts" in wordpress site

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'Music reviews filterable by genre',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-quote',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => false,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'user_can_richedit' => '__return_false',
);

register_post_type('music_review', $args);
```

So, how can I disable visual editor at plugin page and disable add media button?